# Renaming variables to solve recursion method

Tags: variables, math, big-o, recurrence

[image]

I know the idea of renaming the variables that is transforming the recurrence to one that you have seen before.

I'm OK with slide until line 4 .. they renamed T(2^m) with S(m) >> this mean they made 2^m = m

So S(m) should be :
S(m)= 2T(m^(0.5)) + m

also m i think we shouldn't leave m as it is, because it here mean 2^m but they in real are not

Could any one explain this to me?

And also how can i know which variables I should use to make it easy to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you're saying is correct up to the point where you claim that since S(m) = T(2<sup>m</sup>), then m = 2<sup>m</sup>.

The step of defining S(m) = T(2<sup>m</sup>) is similar to defining some new function g in terms of an old function f. For example, if you define a new function g(x) = 2f(5x), you're not saying that x = 5x. You're just defining a new function that's evaluated in terms of f.

So let's see what happens from here. We've defined S(m) = T(2<sup>m</sup>). That means that

> S(m) = T(2<sup>m</sup>)
>
> = 2T(√(2<sup>m</sup>)) + lg (2<sup>m</sup>)

We can do some algebraic simplification to see that

> S(m) = 2T(2<sup>m/2</sup>) + m

And, using the connection between T and S, we see that

> S(m) = 2S(m/2) + m

Notice that we ended up with the recurrence S(m) = 2S(m/2) + m not by just replacing T with S in the original recurrence, but by doing algebraic substitutions and simplifications.

Once we're here, we can use the master theorem to solve S(m) and get that S(m) = O(m log m), so

> T(n) = S(lg n) = O(lg n lg lg n).

As for how you'd come up with this in the first place - that just takes practice. The key insight is that to use the master theorem you need to be shrink the size of the problem down by a constant factor each time, so you need to find a transformation that converts square roots into division by a constant. Square roots are a kind of exponentiation, and logarithms are specifically designed to convert exponentiation into multiplication and division, so it's reasonable to try a log or exponential substitution. Now that you know the trick, I suspect that you'll see it in a lot more places.

Answer (score 1):

You could, as alternative, also just divide the first equation by log(n) to get

```
T(n)/log(n)=T(sqrt(n))/log(sqrt(n)) + 1
```

and then just use

```
S(n) = T(n)/log(n) with S(n) = S(sqrt(n)) + 1
```

or in a different way

```
S(k) = T(n^(2^(-k)))/log(n^(2^(-k)))
```

where then

```
S(k+1)=S(k)+1
```

is again a well-known recursive equation.